# Pure HTML Solution for a Dynamic Widget Using Forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to create a HTML code snippet that I will distribute to third party websites. This code snippet talks to a php file on my server and contains a logic to update the content(image) after specified time intervals. The reason I cannot use JavaScript is that it is not search engine friendly.

The way I have it now is using an HTML+ Javascript code which includes an XMLhttp request and uses Ajax to call a PHP file which in turn reads a csv file and updates the banner image on the third party site. But it is not crawlable by search engines.

Any other way of getting this to work using HTML? Probably using forms?

Comment: I don't think anything that interactive can happen in "pure html"

Comment: I was thinking of having a HTML post request and response. But forms cannot be submit without some human clicking the submit button or having Javascript/Jquery do it. So I am at a dead end basically. :(

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not active. If you want to do something, you need some sort of scripting language. You can do this without using Ajax (XMLhttp). Before Ajax, it was a common practice to relay information to the server using dynamic image loading. Of course, the dynamic image loading required a script. It can be rather simple:

```
<img id='myimg' src='temp.jpg'
onload="document.getElementById('myimg').src='myscript.php?width='+window.innerWidth;"
>
```

Your script replaces the image with whatever you like, but you have information delivered from the web page to your server through the get string. Originally, I saw this used extensively to deliver rotating ads. With this, you can record which ads are shown along with information that would otherwise only be known by the web browser.

Comment: Thanks for your response kainow. But would this solution be SEO friendly? By SEO friendly, I mean that the hyperlink link over the rotating ad image should be visible when I do a page view source.

Comment: When you view source, you should see the original hyperlink, not the updated hyperlink. When you view source, it shows the page as it is when it is originally loaded. It does not show the page once it is altered. If it is important to rotate through images and  have the hyperlink visible in the source, you can load, say, 10 images, but set all except one to "display:none". Then, use a script to cycle through changing the display on them so they show one at a time. Then, the source code will have all the hyperlinks.